# Is It Possible To Open Google Maps By PlaceId in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

In Android one can use an URI to call GoogleMaps as follows

```
https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=47.5951518,-122.3316393&query_place_id=ChIJKxjxuaNqkFQR3CK6O1HNNqY
```

As given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54583821/8738452).

This query opens the GoogleMaps on Android devices and the place info is shown as in the below screenshot:

[image]

I'm looking for a similar result for IOS with GoogleMaps.
I have searched in GoogleMaps SDK documentation and also over the internet but couldn't find an answer.

Can we achieve this for IOS with GoogleMaps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can open Google Maps from your iOS App. There is a [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/ios-urlscheme) available for opening Google Maps Via iOS App.

An example would be:

```
UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string:"https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=47.5951518,-122.3316393&query_place_id=ChIJKxjxuaNqkFQR3CK6O1HNNqY")!)
```

For this to work, there should be Google Maps App installed on the device. Though if you have the Placeid and Google SDK installed on your APP then you must have it's Latitude and Longitude. You can open default Maps to do this task for you. This [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28622266/2299040) Post is a great place to start!

Comment: This is not working. Also, I want the place is selected as in the picture. If we remove the placeID from android query it will not show as in the picture.

Comment: @YunusKarakaya try opening this https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=47.5951518,-122.3316393&query_place_id=ChIJKxjxuaNqkFQR3CK6O1HNNqY

Comment: your comment is what I'm looking for . Please update your answer